# Correct way to handle angular directive "after render"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive in which I want to apply a jQuery plugin. The plugin needs assess the element value during its initialization. But the "link" function in a directive runs before the element has been fully processed by Angular.

Is using a $timeout the correct way to look at an element after it has rendered? What delay should be applied? How do you know this timeout will work consistently across systems and browsers of varying processing power?

http://jsfiddle.net/fergal_doyle/DnrEm/3/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" id="ng-app" ng-controller="test">
    <div ng-repeat="item in list">
        <label>{{item.title}}
            <input type="checkbox" someplugin  ng-checked="item.checked">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("test", function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = [{
        title: "A",
        checked: true
    }, {
        title: "B",
        checked: false
    }, {
        title: "C",
        checked: true
    }];
});

app.directive("someplugin", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            // too soon
            console.log($(element).prop("checked"));

            // works
            $timeout(function(){
             console.log($(element).prop("checked"));
            },0);

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I think you should watch for the model to be available to you in your directive rather than time out

Comment: I think it is fine to use zero $timeout in this case... btw $timeout(fn() {}, 0); equals $timeout(fn(){});, you don't have to use zero number

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
app.directive("someplugin", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // works
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngChecked,function(value){
               console.log(value);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bsw58/1/)

When working with mvc structure like angular, we should not listen to the views for changes as **we should not care** about when angular updates the views.

We should listen to the model instead as model is where we store **the state of the app**.